# What does this selector mean $("link#theme")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm looking at a site template.

I find that when the user clicks on a link, it runs a JavaScript with this command to change the site theme:

```
$('link#theme').attr('href', 'theme2.css');
```

In jQuery what does this selector mean? What object this command change in my page?

Answer (score 5):

This selects a `link` element, with the `theme` id, which is a link to a CSS style sheet.

The `attr` changes the `href`, so that it points to a differnt style sheet, forcing the browser to load a new style sheet.

Remember that to include an style sheet to a page you need to use this element:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme1.css">
```

You can add an id so that the selector finds it, and can manipulate it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme1.css" id="theme">
```